# Unexplainable gap in-between two elements, Flexbox alignment

Tags: html, css

In the process of designing the css layout, I find myself struggling about the unexplainable gap in-between `x-numbers`,`x-letters` and `container-x-image-gallery`.

```css
.uxdesign .x-numbers {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'STT65', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  left: 90px;
  top: -220px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.uxdesign .x-letters {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'STT65', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  left: 90px;
  top: -300px;
}

.container-x-image-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: : 100px;
}

.item-x-image {
  padding: 0 -40px 20px;
  margin: 50px;
  transform: scale(0.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="diciplines">

  <h2 class="uxdesign">
    <p class="x-numbers">01</p>
    <p class="x-letters">UX DESIGN</p>
  </h2>

  <div class="container-x-image-gallery">
    <div class="item-x-image"><img src="components/img/1.png" alt="x_img_one"></div>
    <div class="item-x-image"><img src="components/img/1.png" alt="x_img_two"></div>
  </div>

  <span class="x-description">COMPANY NAME</span>
  <span class="x-date">01/19</span>
```

Adding `height:;` won't help the `flexbox:container` move up.

Im hoping the end result looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: I recommend not using `top` and `left` for relative positioned elements, as it's very hard to understand what the outcome will be. Also, running your snippet does not result in the same layout as in the screenshot.

Comment: What would you recommend then? The site is currently live at https://marcoantonio.netlify.com. I got the suggestion from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I recommend using margin (or padding) instead. If you just want to offset the rendering of an element, I would use the GPU accelerated `transform: translate()` property.

Comment: Thank you for the help, bug is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cristy mentioned, `transform: translate()` is a great alternative to the CSS bug. Since then I have experienced many more issues when it comes to responsive CSS design to anything that has `top` `left` etc. I have started using `margin` a lot more and instead of `px` I am using `vm` `em`. Thank you guys